# lgamma user defined function returns infinite value

Tags: r, user-defined-functions, factorial

This calculates the log of `(x-1)!` to return the `lgamma(x)` value of an integer but my function log_gamma works only till `x = 171` for `x > 171` it returns `Inf`. How can I solve this problem?

```
log_gamma <- function(x){
  y <- 1
  if (x < 1)(
    return("Infinity")
  )
  if (x == 1)(
    return(0)
  )
  x <- x-1
  for (i in 1:x){
     y <- y*i
  }
    return(log(y))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current solution first computes 171! which is a pretty big number.  Instead, use the fact that log(a*b) = log(a) + log(b) to compute this as a sum.

```
log_gamma <- function(x){
  y <- 1
  if (x < 1)(
    return("Infinity")
  )
  if (x == 1)(
    return(0)
  )
  x <- x-1
  for (i in 1:x){
     y <- y + log(i)
  }
    return(y)
}

log_gamma(171)
[1] 707.5731
log_gamma(172)
[1] 712.7147
log_gamma(1000)
[1] 5906.22
```

Comment: Thank you very much